# header on both pages of ToC

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to add a header to most of my pages, all work, however the table of contents doesn't seem to work. Only the second page shows a header (not the first one).

Code in my main file

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{34pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\includegraphics{Images/logo.png}}
\lhead{\textit{\titlename}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
```

Separate toc.tex file

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Ultralight\color{cyan} Inhoudsopgave}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

The header will only show up on the second page of the ToC, how do I get it placed on the first page as well? The footer does show up.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table of contents is typeset as a starred chapter, the reason why the pagestyle is `plain` and not `fancy`. See documentation of `fancyhdr` how the page style can be redefined with `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}`.

Comment: Adding \fancypagestyle{plain}{} did the trick! Thank you.